# Not able to store data in db when trying to insert data from flutter application

Tags: python, mysql, flutter, flask

The application is written in flutter and flask.
[Please refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMGW4.png)

When I click on confirm button, this error pops up on the backend and the data does not get stored in database.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\code\backend\server.py", line 12, in insertvenue
    request_payload = json.loads(request.form['data'])
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\werkzeug\datastructures.py", line 377, in __getitem__
    raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'data'
```

Here is the code:(I've only uploaded the main code of frontend on git)
https://github.com/khushi72/code.git

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Problem:**
Problem inside the backend .You passing the value as json and you receiving as formdata.in the backend side it getting empty.
so change .your flutter side small change. you not properly passed the data

```
request_payload = json.loads(request.form['data'])
```

this

```
request_payload = request.json
```

[Flaskproject-github](https://github.com/lavahasif/flutterflask)

**FrontEnd**

changes on this method

```
Future createPost(String url, {required Map data}) async {

  var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  };


  return http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: json.encode(data),headers: headers).then((http.Response response) {
    final int statusCode = response.statusCode;

    if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400 || json == null) {
      throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
    }
    return Post.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  });
}
```

Insert.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

/*class Data {
  Data ({
    required this.venuename,
    required this.venuetype,
    required this.venueaddress,
    required this.venuecontact,
    required this.venuecost,
    required this.venueimage,
  });

  String venuename;
  String venuetype;
  String venueaddress;
  int venuecontact;
  String venuecost;
  String venueimage;



  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
    //venue_id : json["venue_id"],
    venuename : json["venuename"],
    venuetype : json["venuetype"],
    venueaddress : json["venueaddress"],
    venuecontact :json["venuecontact"],
    venuecost: json["venuecost"],
    venueimage :json["venueimage"],



  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {

    //"venue_id" : venue_id,
    "venuename" : venuename,
    "venuetype" : venuetype,
    "venueaddress" : venueaddress,
    "venuecontact" : venuecontact,
    "venuecost" : venuecost,
    "venueimage": venueimage,

  };
}*/
/*Future createPost(String url, {Map }) async {
  /*return http.post(url, body: body).then((http.Response response) {
    final int statusCode = response.statusCode;

    if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400 || json == null) {
      throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
    }
    return Post.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  });*/
}*/

class Post {
  final String venuename;
  final String venuetype;
  final String venueaddress;
  final String venuecontact;
  final String venuecost;
  final String venueimage;
  final String venuelimit;

  Post(
      {required this.venuename,
      required this.venuetype,
      required this.venueaddress,
      required this.venuecontact,
      required this.venuecost,
      required this.venueimage,
      required this.venuelimit});

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
      venuelimit: json['venuelimit'],
      venuename: json['venuename'],
      venuetype: json['venuetype'],
      venueaddress: json['venueaddress'],
      venuecontact: json['venuecontact'],
      venuecost: json['venuecost'],
      venueimage: json['venueimage'],
    );
  }

  Map toMap() {
    var map = new Map();
    map["venuename"] = venuename;
    map["venuetype"] = venuetype;
    map["venueaddress"] = venueaddress;
    map["venuecontact"] = venuecontact;
    map["venuecost"] = venuecost;
    map["venueimage"] = venueimage;
    map["venuelimit"] = venuelimit;

    return map;
  }
}

Future createPost(String url, {required Map data}) async {

  var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  };
  

  return http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: json.encode(data),headers: headers).then((http.Response response) {
    final int statusCode = response.statusCode;

    if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400 || json == null) {
      throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
    }
    return Post.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  });
}

class InsertData extends StatefulWidget {
  const InsertData({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  //final Future post;
  @override
  State<InsertData> createState() => _InsertDataState();
}

class _InsertDataState extends State<InsertData> {
  static final CREATE_POST_URL = 'http://192.168.45.156:5000/insertvenue';
  TextEditingController venuenameController =
      new TextEditingController(text: "sdf");
  TextEditingController venuetypeController =
      new TextEditingController(text: "sdf");
  TextEditingController venueaddressController =
      new TextEditingController(text: "sdf");
  TextEditingController venuecontactController =
      new TextEditingController(text: "sdf");
  TextEditingController venuecostController =
      new TextEditingController(text: "sdf");
  TextEditingController venueimageController =
      new TextEditingController(text: "sdf");
  TextEditingController venuelimitController =
      new TextEditingController(text: "sdf");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: venuenameController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                ),
                labelText: "VenueName",
                hintText: "VenueName",
                floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.pink.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 9,
                ),
                errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.red.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 9,
                ),
                focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.red.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 9,
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.pink.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 5,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: venuetypeController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                ),
                labelText: "VenueName",
                hintText: "VenueName",
                floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.pink.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 9,
                ),
                errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.red.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 9,
                ),
                focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.red.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 9,
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.pink.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 5,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: venuelimitController,
              inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                ),
                labelText: "Venuelimit",
                hintText: "Venuelimit",
                floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.pink.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 9,
                ),
                errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.red.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 9,
                ),
                focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.red.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 9,
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.pink.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 5,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: venueaddressController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                ),
                labelText: "VenuAddress",
                hintText: "VenueAddress",
                floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.pink.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 9,
                ),
                errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.red.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 9,
                ),
                focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.red.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 9,
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.pink.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 5,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: venuecontactController,
              inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                ),
                labelText: "VenueContact",
                hintText: "Contact",
                floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.pink.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 9,
                ),
                errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.red.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 9,
                ),
                focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.red.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 9,
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.pink.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 5,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: venueimageController,
              inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                ),
                labelText: "VenueImg",
                hintText: "Image",
                floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.pink.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 9,
                ),
                errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.red.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 9,
                ),
                focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.red.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 9,
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.pink.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 5,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: venuecostController,
              inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                ),
                labelText: "Venuecost",
                hintText: "Cost",
                floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.pink.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 9,
                ),
                errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.red.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 9,
                ),
                focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.red.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 9,
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.pink.shade900,
                  ),
                  //gapPadding: 5,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                ///int cimage = (venueimageController.text);
                // int climit = int.parse(venuelimitController.text);
                //int ccontact = int.parse(venuecontactController.text);
                //double ccost = double.parse(venuecostController.text);
                Post newPost = new Post(
                    venuename: venuenameController.text,
                    venueaddress: venueaddressController.text,
                    venuecost: venuecostController.text,
                    venuetype: venuetypeController.text,
                    venueimage: venueimageController.text,
                    venuelimit: venuelimitController.text,
                    venuecontact: venuecontactController.text);
                print(json.encode(newPost.toMap()));
                Post p =
                    await createPost(CREATE_POST_URL, data: newPost.toMap());
                print(newPost.toMap());
                print(p.venuename);
              },
              child: Text("Confirm"),
              color: Colors.red[900],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Backend**

backend mainly change here .i already changes in backend side please run this code

```
  def insertvenue():
        request_payload = request.json   //here
        # request_payload = json.loads(request.json)
        venue_id = venue.insert_venue(request_payload)
```

***SErver.py***

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import json

from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

# from venue import server_connection
import venue

# connection=server_connection

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/insertvenue', methods=['POST'])
def insertvenue():
    request_payload = request.json
    # request_payload = json.loads(request.json)
    venue_id = venue.insert_venue(request_payload)
    response = jsonify(venue_id)
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="192.168.45.156", debug=True, port=5000)
```

**Venue.py**

```
# from flask.ext import mysql
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL


from flask import app, Flask

global __mydb


# def server_connection():
#     __mydb = None
#     if __mydb is None:
#         __mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
#             host='localhost:3306',
#             user='root',
#             password='',
#             database='planner'
#         )
#     return __mydb


# app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
# app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
# app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
# app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'MyDB'
app = Flask(__name__)
mysql = MySQL()
app.config.setdefault('MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost')
app.config.setdefault('MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT', 3306)
app.config.setdefault('MYSQL_DATABASE_USER', 'root')
app.config.setdefault('MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD', '')
app.config.setdefault('MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD', '')
app.config.setdefault('MYSQL_DATABASE_DB', 'planner')
mysql.init_app(app)


def insert_venue( venues):
    conn = mysql.connect()
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    query = (
        "INSERT INTO venue(venuename,venuetype,venueaddress,venuecost,venuecontact,venuelimit,venueimage) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)")
    data = (venues['venuename'], venues['venuetype'], venues['venueaddress'],
            venues['venuecost'], venues['venuecontact'], venues['venuelimit'], venues['venueimage'])
    s=cursor.execute(query, data)
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    return  venues



    # connection.commit()


# if __name__ == '__main__':
    # connection = server_connection()
```

install mysql driver

```
pip install flask-mysql
```

reference https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: I have made the required changes but still getting error.

Comment: please change ip address inside the flutter code .and add your ip

Comment: have already done that.

Comment: I have mysql driver installed.

Comment: just use i mention package and my code then try it will works

Comment: Not working. I modified my code and tried running it and then I tried running your code but I'm getting the same error in both cases. I have all the packages installed as well. I have posted the recent error above and the modified code on git hub.

Comment: i already tested my code  works.so my humble request consider my code .for testing you create new flask project  and add my code and  .i mentioned mysql pacakge .it will defenitly works

Comment: i definitly help you .i check your github code .consider my solution  and run and  implement on your side after running

Comment: It worked :) I cold booted the emulator and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: if it helpful please upvote my answer